# SQL not executing in java method

Tags: java, sql

I wrote a method in java to execute some SQL but it doesn't seem to be executing(In the debugger it isn't showing me any values returned, just the sql as a string). I think theres an issue with me inserting the ID as it would be a duplicate but not sure how to solve that.

```
 public void addPrevious(TodaysDate Date){
        String id = ("SELECT ID FROM table1 where DATE_ = (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
        String paymentDate = ("SELECT PAYMENTDATE FROM table1  where DATE = (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
        String reportingUnit = ("SELECT REPORTING_UNIT FROM table1  where DATE = (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
        String insertLastDate =  ("INSERT INTO table1(PAYMENTDATE, REPORTING_UNIT, DATE) VALUES  ("+id+" ,"+paymentDate+", "+amount+", "+asOfDate+")");

    }
```

I'm attempting to add the previous days results to the same table with a updated date so it displays for the current date as well, the program only displays the current dates results. TodaysDate Class handles getting the current date

Comment: This method does not execute anything. It just stores sql statements in variables.

Comment: @forpas is declaring it as strings the wrong thing to do?

Comment: Simply defining a String variable will not "execute" anything. It merely defines - well - a String value. Java doesn't care whether that string contains `select * from table1` or `this is a string`

Comment: Does this compile: `public void addPrevious(TodaysDate Date){`. You can provide some details like the input table structure, data and expected results -  as example data/rows. Also, show what was the result you got.